# How can I re-use a tweenmax tween in a pre-built content slider?

Tags: jquery, gsap, cycle2

I have a tween affecting elements multiple slides. Currently when the slider is initialized, I'm just playing the tween each time, but it's affecting the element with the targeted class in EVERY slide, not just the current slide and sometimes you can see the hidden element show up while the tween is happening.

Is there a way to set up a tween with tweenmax so that it's re-usable on elements with the same class, but not run at the same time?

The code:

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1) center center / cover no-repeat;">
            <span class="slide-text">
                <h2>Heading Text</h2>
                <h3>Subheader Text</h3>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/3) center center / cover no-repeat;">
            <span class="slide-text">
                <h2>Heading Text</h2>
                <h3>Subheader Text</h3>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slide-direction">
        <div class="prev-slide"></div>
        <div class="next-slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var dropIn = TweenMax.from(".slides .slide-text", 0.75, {top: "-400px", transform: "scale(0.5)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)});
        $(".slides").cycle({
            // options
            slides: '>li',
            timeout: 4500,
            speed: 1450, // Transition speed. This must give the tween on the .slide-text enough time to complete the reversal out
            manualSpeed: 1450,
            next: '.slide-direction .next-slide',
            prev: '.slide-direction .prev-slide',
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipe: true,
            swipeFx: 'fade'
        }).on('cycle-initialized', function(currSlide){
            // when the slider is fully loaded
            dropIn.play();
        }).on('cycle-after', function(currSlide){
            // when the slide transition is completed
            dropIn.play();
        }).on('cycle-before', function(currSlide){
            // just before the transition is started
            dropIn.reverse();
        });

    });
</script>
```

[See the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jzeleny/st2cfy5u/)

Comment: when you say "affecting multiple slides", do you mean that you have multiple `.slides` elements in your actual project because I only see one `.slides` element in your fiddle at least and everything seems to be working fine there. Or do you mean that the text elements that are animated by `TweenMax` (i.e. your `.slides .slide-text` elements) are both happening at the same time. This is a problem if you inspect it yes since both the `.slides .slide-text` elements are animated at the same time, but visually, it looks fine because the parent `li` element's `visibility` gets set to `hidden`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue. I don't want the tween to affect anything but the slide that is currently active, but I would like it if the tween is re-usable without writing the same tween over and over with different id's on the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Since there is no way to re-use a tweenmax tween set by a variable (that I could find...), this is what I ended up doing:

```
        // Set the initialized state before the slider is initialized
        $(document).on('cycle-initialized', ".slides", function(){
            // when the slider is fully loaded
            TweenMax.fromTo(
                $(".cycle-slide-active .slide-text"), 0.75, {top: "-400px", transform: "scale(0.5)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}, {top: "120px", transform: "scale(1)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}
            );
        })

        var homeSlider = $(".slides").cycle({
            // options
            slides: '>li',
            timeout: 4500,
            speed: 1450,
            manualSpeed: 1450,
            next: '.slide-direction .next-slide',
            prev: '.slide-direction .prev-slide',
            pauseOnHover: true,
            autoHeight: 1,
            swipe: true,
            swipeFx: 'fade'
        }).on('cycle-after', function(){
            // when the slide transition is completed
            TweenMax.fromTo(
                $(".cycle-slide-active .slide-text"), 0.75, {top: "-400px", transform: "scale(0.5)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}, {top: "120px", transform: "scale(1)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}
            );
        }).on('cycle-before', function(){
            // just before the transition is started
            TweenMax.fromTo(
                $(".cycle-slide-active .slide-text"), 0.75, {top: "120px", transform: "scale(1)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}, {top: "-400px", transform: "scale(0.5)", ease: Back.easeOut.config(1)}
            );
        });
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzeleny/st2cfy5u/)

Comment: when animating with CSS in GSAP. you should use `y` instead of `top` .. also instead of `transform:"scale(0.5)"` you can use `scale:0.5` instead .. You can store your Tweenmax tweens in a variable for later use. I think what your dealing with is a scope issue with the jQuery cycle() plugin callbacks

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'll keep that in mind on my future tweens and javascript animations.